# XCode 6.3.1 Launch Images Source not working with asset catalog

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode6

XCode 6.3.1
iOS 8.3
iPhone 5S

I created a new Game Application ( SpriteKit ) in XCode and specified Swift as the language.

- Added launch image using asset catalog
- Deleted LaunchScreen.xib from info.plist
- Changed Launch Images Source in target->general to point to asset catalog

When I launch the app on my phone I get a black screen for a few seconds and then the app shows up.

How do I specify a launch screen in XCode that supports iOS 7 & 8?

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if you have select your App Icon inside your target
[image]

2) Verify you have ALL images in your app icon set. (I'm exclude Watch Icons and Car Play, but if you need it you must add it inside your icon set)

[image]